# how to find highly cited articles in journals with low impact factor?

Tags: citations, journals, bibliometrics, impact-factor

Journals with high IF get more attention, so might get "better" articles.
However I am interested in finding papers published in minor journals that have a high number of citations, say >100.

I can't seem to do this search on web of science. How is this achieved?

Comment: http://scholar.google.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scopus](http://www.scopus.com/) allows you to do this. Search for the journal name and then sort by number of citations.

Comment: but I would like to do a global search perhaps by doing a double sort IF and n of citations.

Comment: I think you can do this in Scopus (see the "compare journals" option). It uses a slightly different metric since impact factor is privately owned.